# $_POST variable does not encode as MD5 hash when updating database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

I'm doing this as a proof of concept to test my ability, I am aware that MD5 is not secure to use for passwords.

I have a login page which works fine by creating a MD5 has of the entered password and checking the hash against the value stored in the database.

I have created a page where the user can change there username (email address) and in order for this to happen firstly:

1. The ID for that user is placed in the $_SESSION[id] variable. This is sent with the UPDATE SQL command to ensure the correct users email address is changed.
2. The password has to be re-entered for extra authentication. This isn't a problem however the value is in plain text and not MD5 so the UPDATE SQL command fails and 0 rows are updated. I have used md5($_POST['password'] (See line 17 of code)

   ```
   <?php
   require_once __DIR__ . ('/../config/init.php');
   if($_SESSION['login'] != 1)
   {
       header('Location: /login/');

   }
       if($_POST){

       $mysqli = new mysqli($db['hostname'], $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['database']);

       /* check connection */
       if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
           printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
           exit();
       }
       $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET email = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']) . "' WHERE password = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, md5($_POST['password'])) . "' AND id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");

       if($result == 1)
       {
           echo "Email successfully updated. Please attempt to log in with your existing password";
           print_r($_POST);
           print_r($_SESSION);
           echo md5($_POST['password']);
       }
       else{
           echo "epic fail";

       }
   }
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <?php 
       include INCLUDES . 'head_tags.php';
   ?>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class='container'>
       <?php
           include INCLUDES . 'header.php';
           include INCLUDES . 'nav.php';
       ?>
       <div class='two-thirds column'>
           <h2>User control panel</h2>
           <p>Welcome to the secure page <?php echo $_SESSION['forename'], " ", $_SESSION['surname'];?></p>
           <p>You are currently registered with email address <?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></p>

           <h2>Change user details</h2>
           <p>If you would like to change your email address. Please complete the form below</p>

           <form action='#' method='post'>
           <div>
           <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
           <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="on" required>
           <label for="password">Password:</label>
           <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Existing Password" autocomplete="on" required>
           </div>

           <input type='submit' value='submit'>
           </form>


       </div>
   </div>
   <?php
       include INCLUDES . 'footer.php';
   ?>
   ```

These lines would not normally be in the code but I have been trying to debug.

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_SESSION);
echo md5($_POST['password'])
```

on print_r($_POST) it is in plain text in the array
echoing the $_POST['password'] as md5 returns the password as MD5. It is an exact match as whats in the database.

Any help will be great :).

Comment: assign the querry to a string and echo that

Comment: This is the output @Dagon

$ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 0 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0 [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.20 [server_version] => 50620 [stat] => Uptime: 49119 Threads: 1 Questions: 479 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 128 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 64 Queries per second avg: 0.009 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 91 [warning_count] => 0 )